# Check if two arithmetic expressions are equivalent?

Tags: arithmetic, equivalence-relations

I have to use arithmetic expressions and I need to know if two expressions are equivalent, i.e do they yield the same result and if written slightly different, do they represent the same expression?

For example, $5*7$ is equivalent to $7*5$, or $(4*3 + 3*2) \iff (3*2 + 4*3)$.
Yes, division and subtraction are not commutative.

Apart from the result, what else can tell me mathematically that two arithmetic expressions are equivalent?
What is the general math answer to this question?

Comment: As a computer scientist, have you had lectures on the **theory of languages** ? This is the main keyword. Then, there are many other "sub-keywords", in particular, tree representation of an arithmetic expressions, well formed expressions, etc...

Comment: Hmm, I thought so, that arithmetic expression can be written as a tree structure

Comment: You can use the properties of a field, such as associativity and commutativity of addition and multiplication, additive and multiplicative identities $0$ and $1$ and inverses, and distributivity of multiplication over addition

Comment: Have you heard about the so-called "prefixed expressions" sometimes known as "Polish (or inversed Polish) notation" : "operand operand operator" replacing the "infixed notation" : "operand operator operand". This is maybe the key to your problem... (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation)

Comment: Yes I have heard about this inverse notation. Its been a while. I have forgotten it seems. So if I represent two expressions in inverse notation and if they are equivalent, they should have same inverse notations?

Comment: Well partially, yes. Division is not commutative.

Comment: 1) I wasn't warned about your answer : you have to give the pseudo of the person with whom you want to interact. 2) No, there is no uniqueness: the single (but considerable) advantage is that in the Polish notation, there is no need for parentheses. But the general problem is not simple: you must look for a specific algorithm about equivalences on trees.

Comment: ok, thanks. Have to think a bit, read some theory, and come back with an answer. Or maybe delete the question.

Comment: No need to delete the question.

Comment: If you don't have access to Mathematica, you can always use Wolfram Alpha. e.g., `4 * 3 + 3 * 2 == 3 * 2 + 3 * 4`